# save big num in magento product price

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I wanna set this number **100000000000** to my product price but Magento change it to **100000000** and it doesn't save it correctly

how can I fix it?

**magento version 1.9**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the limitations of the columns definition in MySQL: The columns where prices are stored are all of type `decimal(12,4)`. That means that you can store only prices with a maximum of 12 digits in total where 4 are digital points. So the maximum value that can be stored is `99999999.9999` and rounded `100000000`.

In order to allow greater values you will need to change all the corresponding database fields from `decimal(12,4)` to something larger. To work with prices of `100000000000` you need at least 4 more digits because the value will be summed for example in checkout process (3 digits would allow a maximum of `99999999999.9999` rounded exactly your required price `100000000000`). That would mean to change the affected columns from `decimal(12,4)` to `decimal(16,4)`

The MySQL command to perform a change like this for a column is:

```
alter table [YOUR TABLENAME] modify [YOUR COLUMN] decimal(16,4);
```

**Be aware that there are lots of affected columns in Magentos database!**

Starting with `value` in table `catalog_product_entity_decimal` (where the price product attributes are stored, going to and the price columns in `sales_flat_quote_item`,`sales_flat_order_item` etc. to the total columns in `sales_flat_quote`,`sales_flat_order`, `sales_flat_order_grid`,`sales_flat_invoice`,`sales_flat_invoice_gird` etc. (e.g. `base_subtotal`,`subtotal`,`base_grand_total`, `grand_total`). This list is not complete!

And there may be some more tables / columns affected depending on your maximum order value, tax calculation etc.

> You should also be aware that changing database definitions on core
>   Magento fields my cause conflicts with later updates or potential
>   migrations to Magento 2.**
>
> If you want to go that way you should analyze your settings to
>   identify all the needed columns, make the changes in a local /
>   development environment and test them before rolling them out in
>   production!